# Error en los permisos de la galeria del usuario en flutter

Tags: android, flutter, programación-móvil, permisos

El programa trata de subir fotos desde tu galeria pero tengo un problema con image_picker. al construir apk_release no ingresa a la galería, pero en el apk_debug sí ingresa. ¿Cómo podría resolver eso o el apk_debug si funciona para Play Store?

cuando pruebo en el debug si vale todo solo ocurre al poner en desarrollo el proyecto.
¿Cómo puedo solucionar este error?

mi manifest esta en el main peor no se por que es el error

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.example.adopmask">
        <!-- io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication is an android.app.Application that
             calls FlutterMain.startInitialization(this); in its onCreate method.
             In most cases you can leave this as-is, but you if you want to provide
             additional functionality it is fine to subclass or reimplement
             FlutterApplication and put your custom class here. -->
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" />
    
    
       
        </application>
        
    </manifest>
```

Errores en el log

```
 E/ClipboardService: Denying clipboard access to com.google.android.gms, application is not in focus nor is it a system service for user 0
E/ClipboardService: Denying clipboard access to com.android.chrome, application is not in focus nor is it a system service for user 0
E/ClipboardService: Denying clipboard access to com.google.android.gms, application is not in focus nor is it a system service for user 0
 E/ClipboardService: Denying clipboard access to com.android.chrome, application is not in focus nor is it a system service for user 0
E/ClipboardService: Denying clipboard access to com.kaidriu.YouPet, application is not in focus nor is it a system service for user 0
 E/wifi_forwarder: qemu_pipe_open_ns:62: Could not connect to the 'pipe:qemud:wififorward' service: Invalid argument
 E/wifi_forwarder: RemoteConnection failed to initialize: RemoteConnection failed to open pipe
E/ClipboardService: Denying clipboard access to com.kaidriu.YouPet, application is not in focus nor is it a system service for user 0
E/android.system.suspend@1.0-service: Error opening kernel wakelock stats for: wakeup34: Permission denied
E/android.system.suspend@1.0-service: Error opening kernel wakelock stats for: wakeup35: Permission denied
```

y si doy otra vez click en el boton para entrar a la galeria sale

```
 E/flutter: [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(186)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(already_active, Image picker is already active, null, null)
    #0      StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope (package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:581)
    #1      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:158)
    <asynchronous suspension>
    #2      ImagePicker.pickImage (package:image_picker/image_picker.dart:61)
    <asynchronous suspension>
    #3      _Perdidos2PageState._openCamaraP (package:adopmask/src/features/presentation/perdidos2_page/view/perdidos2_page.dart:61)
    <asynchronous suspension>
```

El emulador que uso es el Pixel 4 API 30 android 10 pero tambien lo he probado en el Pixel 4XL API 30 y Samsung A30 android10

Pude solucionar el error bajando la versión del complemento del gradle a 3.5.0 no se a que se debe esto pero funciono.

Comment: en que dispositivo los estas probando? que modelo/version ?

Comment: por otro lado que error sucede? viste el log?  abre android studio, tu proyecto, la pestaña del logcat,  reproduce el error y mira el log , añadelo a tu pregunta